Software or database for creating my own bentcher or song book
I'm trying to create a family bentcher and/or song book. Which software systems do you recommend for creating a database of songs that include Hebrew, English, and Transliteration? And for the layout of the final product?

I did one using a word doc that I converted to pdf and uploaded to lulu (and was able to tailor it with English and other texts)

Word/Docs + Google
